# How to check if my array of dictionaries has certain dictionary?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have two arrays of dictionaries with type [String: String]. 
How can I check if one array contains dictionary from another.

```
    let firstArray: [[String: String]] = [dict1, dict2, dict3]
    let secondArray: [[String: String]] = [dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4, dict5]
```

I tried to do this with contains() method

```
    for item in firstArray {
        if secondArray.contains(item) {
            print("Hello")
        }
    }
```

but it throw an error there. So what's the best way to do this?

Comment: What was the error thrown?

Comment: [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ziatc5ljfzs6wsx/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202017-01-07%2015.50.25.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the predicate form of `contains` to accomplish this:

```
for item in firstArray {
    if secondArray.contains(where: { $0 == item })  {
        print("Hello")
    }
}
```

You can't use the other form of `contains` because type `[String : String]` does not conform to the *Equatable* protocol.

Comment: Thanks. That helped :)

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in **Swift 4**

```
let dictionary = ["abc":"pqr"]

if !myArray.contains{ $0 == dictionary } {
           //append dictionary inside array        
           myArray.append(dictionary)
   }
else {
     //dictionary already exist in your myArray
   }
```